# Why does a reduction in regional differences in unemployment shift the Phillips curve?

Tags: inflation, unemployment, natural-rate-unemployment

According to this question below, apparently a reduction in the regional differences in the level of unemployment would shift the short run Phillips curve SRPC leftwards. The answer to the question is A).

I do not see how this could be the case, because "a reduction in the regional differences in the level of unemployment" could mean the regions could either all experience more unemployment, or could all experience less unemployment. I don't see how either scenario would affect the expectation for inflation (in this question it would seem to be a deflationary expectation) to result in a leftwards shift in the SRPC.

[image]